# Read osm map tags using networkx

Tags: python, openstreetmap, josm, networkx

I downloaded part of a map using JOSM, and saved it in .osm. I am reading the same file using networkx in python. When I read the attribute of an edge, it gives me something like this:

```
{'ShpName': 'streets_all', 'Json': '{ "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 55.4509595, 25.2316337 ], [ 55.4508415, 25.2311484 ] ] }', 'Wkb': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02@K\xb9\xb9\nx)\x07@9;LX\x9e&\xc7@K\xb9\xb5,\x9d\x16\xfd@9;,\x8a\xa2\x85\xd1', 'id': 169108307, 'Wkt': 'LINESTRING (55.4509595 25.2316337,55.4508415 25.2311484)'}
```

My code to read the above is:

```
G_streets = nx.read_shp("D:\\osm_maps\\streets_all.shp", simplify=False)
for n1,n2 in G_streets.edges_iter():
    print G_streets.edge[n1][n2]
```

I would like to read information related to streets like: maxspeed, oneway, highway, name, ref. In JOSM, all of those are stored as tags. These tags do not appear on the above structure. Am I doing the right thing? and how can I read these tags?

UPDATE:
Please note that I use QGIS to import the .osm file and convert it to shp file.

Comment: They may not appear, perhaps because they are not in the database. Are you checking like-for-like cases? Perhaps you need to save in some other format in JOSM, or use original source data.

Comment: Is it mandatory to import it in Qgis and convert to shp?